# conditional rendering is not working in vuejs v-if

Tags: vue.js, conditional-rendering

i have a span tag which is conditionally rendered using v-if in vuejs. if user is null then it should
not be rendered and if user is not null then only it should be rendered. now when a user logged in, it
is  being displayed, upto here its working, but when user click on logout, then it should not rendered but still its rendering

My code snippet is below

```
    <span class="user-options" id="user-opt" v-if="user">
      <ul class="user-details">
        <li style="background: #000000; color: white; text-align: center; line-height: 30px;">
          Welcome&nbsp;{{ user.username }}
        </li>
        <li style="text-align: center; background: white; color: black; line-height: 30px;">
          email&nbsp;{{ user.username }}
        </li>
        <li style="background: white; color: black; line-height: 30px;" v-if="user.verified">
          verified
          <span style="float: right; color: blue;">
            <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
          </span>
        </li>
        <li style="line-height: 30px;" v-if="user.verified">
          total post
          <span style="float: right">
            {{ user.totalPost }}
          </span>
        </li>
        <li style="text-align: center; line-height: 30px;" v-on:click="logOut">
          logout
        </li>
      </ul>
</span>
```

[image: when user is not null its showing user description]

when user click logout still its showing untill i refresh the page its rendering some content of span tag
[image]

Comment: Could you use VueJS dev tools in your web browser to check what the Value of `user` is and show it in the question. Its like `user` is not null

Comment: user is object which contain properties like username, email, verified, totalpost etc

Comment: can you add your code performs logout?

Comment: thanks for your reply , i found the bug and fixed it

Answer (score -1):

problem was v-if="user"

```
<span class="user-options" id="user-opt" v-if="user ">
```

instead of above i used this code and everything is resolved

```
  <span class="user-options" id="user-opt" v-if="user != null">
```